# External JavaScript onclick instead of inline HTML onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm quite new to JavaScript and I need some help with my code. I made a little story about racing in a formula 1 car against Michael Schumacher.

In this game you could choose your car by clicking on the image and then proceed, but my teacher said it wasn't good enough. She gave me feedback and she told me that I needed to put the HTML **img onclick** into my JavaScript.

I don't know what to do and where to put it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: also, this is the link to my code https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~felthud001/dt3/index.html

Comment: Has your teacher not taught you this, or are you expected to research this for yourself? What, precisely, was the feedback? And, seriously, this is a college level education?

Comment: well this is the basic stuff. I wanted to do this. Im from the Netherlands and this is the first class of many of Javascript. In the future we will get Javascript 2 and 3 where it is getting more advanced. My teacher said: No it is not right to put the Javascript in to the HTML file. I want it external (in the js file). So i went looking for solutions but i havent found and that could help me solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

First, add an id attribute to your image tag, for example one would

```
<img id='car1'/>
```

or

```
<img id='car2'/>
```

then use the addEventListener method to add the event listener, like so:

```
document.getElementById('car1').addEventListener('click', functionName, false);
document.getElementById('car2').addEventListener('click', functionName, false);
```

This function takes 3 arguments, the first is the type of event (click) the second is the name of the function you want to call, and the third is how the event is captured (just leave this as false).  Then, create a function in your javascript called onPageLoad and put the two lines of code inside it:

```
function onPageLoad(){
    document.getElementById('car1').addEventListener('click', functionName, false);
    document.getElementById('car2').addEventListener('click', functionName, false);
}
```

Finally, add this line of code at the end of your page to start the whole process:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onPageLoad, false);
```

Comment: you see, i have no doubt your code wouldnt work but im such a newb in Javascript that I havent got a clue where to put it... im sorry

Comment: Just add it to the top of your document either between script tags or in your external javascript file.